# Which SObjects represent Native CMS Content in Communities and can they be accessed?

Tags: lightning-community

Salesforce released a Beta CMS product for their Communities product. In it, you can create basic CMS content for publication to your communities site. It's unclear from any of salesforces' documentation where this content is actually stored in salesforce.

I would like to create custom components that use the cms content similar to the existing components that render the content but with some added functionality. There are two questions I'd like answered

1. Where is the CMS content created with the content editor stored in salesforce? (In other words which SObject represent the CMS content)?
2. Is it possible to access these SObject records through apex or some other API?

Comment: This question needs to be re-opened.
It is relevant and looks to be quite clear. It is not rocket science people.
This is also an evolving Product from Salesforce so do it the courtesy of allowing for answers that evolve over time just like the product will.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the object is called ManagedContent, but it's not supported by SOQL yet.

Attempted a simple query [SELECT Id FROM ManagedContent LIMIT 1] resulted in the following error

[image]

The answer is no, CMS Content is not accessible through SOQL and there are no connect api calls available

Searching for CMS Content or CMS in the connect api reference results in "No Results Found"

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_connect_api.htm?search_text=CMS%20Content

Comment: This post landed in the `Low Quality Posts` review queue. It would be improved if you **[edit]** it to add any sort of supporting documentation or links that you used to make this discovery. If you include links, please also cite the relevant content here.

Comment: I couldn't find anything in the documentation but querying for ManagedContent object resulted in "This object is not supported for SOQL"

Answer (score 5):

I am also using CMS Content (Salesforce CMS) in Lightning Community.

Unfortunately, for now, it has very limited customization options and it's not yet supported by APIs. For all available options, you can follow to [help](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=community_managed_content_overview.htm&type=5)

So, for now, you are limited to standard Components.

If you want to do some customization I would suggest creating custom CSS on Community. Even though it's generally not the best practice, I don't see other option available.

Here is an example of what I'm using.

```css
.js-content-body h2 {
    color: blue;
    font-size: 1.3em;
}
.ui-widget > div > .js-content .js-content-title p {
    margin: auto;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
.js-content-header .js-content-subtitle {
    color: gray;
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 80%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping I was missing something obvious. This is great for changing the look of it but we're trying to do something a little more dynamic with content within content pages. Looks like we'll be stuck doing things with sObjects for a little longer.