# Global Search Bar component not available in Build Your Own community template

Tags: lightning, community, community-builder

I have configured a Lightning Community using the Build Your Own template. I wish to add a global search box like the ones in the headers of most of the built in templates, to allow my users to search for CMS content.  [This documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=rss_component_reference_table.htm&type=5) implies that I should be able to use the Global Search Box component, however, it's not available for me to drag into the builder. Does it need to be activated or enabled?

Answer (score 3):

So as it appears that you would need a custom one to place in here. Else it will use the default search component. You can try, if you're not seeing anything search related on your page, to update the settings to **show all components** but it also notes that some may not function well depending on page types.

[image]

[image]

Comment: So it looks like this should work - my problem is (and I probably should have explained this use case) that this search box is only supposed to display ManagedContent objects (CMS articles) and currently they can't be queried (see here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/261274/which-sobjects-represent-native-cms-content-in-communities-and-can-they-be-acces), which I would need to do when implementing the custom search.  However, it looks like the native search supports them: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=community_managed_content_search_content.htm&type=5

Comment: Then i would have to move to say that if these are not supported in a custom one to replace it, then the answer is that you cannot, at this time, do it with these objects.

Answer (score 1):

If your template has a placeholder for search, then you can add the search via navigating to

> Setup >All Community > Builder > Settings (4th Icon on left)

There, expand the theme by clicking setting icons next to the Theme Layout Component and choose the global search component or your custom search component.

[image: Community Settings]

Comment: This template neither has a placeholder for search (it's just an empty Build Your Own template), nor a custom search component.  I want to use the default global search box component (see the link in my question) and be able to put it anywhere in my community.